# malloc and free in .h and .c while using language c

Tags: c, malloc, free

I'm new to C programming and I'm really confused about `malloc()` and `free()`.

I need to read some random number of random data values from file (.yaml) and store them in hashmap, something like `< char *key_name, char *type, void *value >`.

I'm using `void *` pointer to store any type data which I read as `char *`, and so I wanted to write my own function which will determine data type and return right sized pointer to pass it for further tasks.

I want this function to be at my little parser (myparser.h and myparser.c) to use it as a library in the future.

But! For instance I have this piece of code in myparser.c executing for **each float value that is read:**

```
void *parser_get_pointer(char *token_value, char *type) {
...    
else if (strcmp(type, "float") == 0) {
    printf("Type float recognized\n");

    float *fp = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
    *fp = atof(token_value);

    void *result = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
    result = fp;


     return (float *)result;
    }
...
}
```

And the main question is where should I do `free(fp)` so I do not lose data in main.c?

Comment: You call free() when you no longer need the data. Nobody can answer where in your program that is except you. What people can offer (and I'm sure someone will) is that you need to spend less time casting types around!

Comment: A `void` pointer doesn't know what it points to, both `void *result = (float *)malloc(...)` and `return (float *)result;` delete any type information. And as long as the data in allocated storage is needed, it mustn't be freed. The whole design looks flawed and the general problem to solve isn't clear enough to me to suggest a better design.

Comment: there is a leak where you allocate data for `result` but then assign `fp` to `result` and losing address of previously allocated data

Comment: Please clarify what you really want to do. As-is, the best one can say about the question is that this code doesn't do anything useful. It looks a little like you're trying to implement a run-time type system, what looks quite ahead of what you've learned so far. I suggest getting more familiar with C and programming in general before spending more time on that project.

Comment: Also consider giving "Valgrind" a try : it is a good tool that tracks memory leaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***A few generally accepted thoughts*** on ***malloc()***, ***calloc()*** and ***realloc()*** function use:

***1)*** do not cast the return of these functions when using C.

```
int *a = (int)malloc(10*sizeof(int)); //wrong
int *a = malloc(10*sizeof(int)); //correct
```

***2)*** check the return value of function

```
int *a = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
a[0] = 10; //wrong - if malloc failed, a will be  NULL.

int *a = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
if(a)
{
    a[0] = 10; //correct
```

***3)*** In the case of realloc() use a tmp variable to avoid memory leak

```
tmp = realloc(orig, newsize);
if (tmp == NULL)
{
    // could not realloc, but orig still valid
}
else
{
    orig = tmp;
}
```

***4)*** Always call free() once for each call of ***[c][m][re]alloc()***

```
int *a = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
if(a)
{
    a[0] = 10; //correct
    ...
    free(a);  
}
else
{
     //handle error
}
```

Not doing so ***will*** result in memory leaks.

Comment: Not checking for a valid pointer returned from malloc will never result in a memory leak, but it may result in an exception that kills the program or worse, depending on a number of factors.

Comment: @mah - Yep.  Overstated.  I was thinking of the realloc() scenario.   Edited code.

Comment: In Number4, shouldn't `free` be in the body of the `if`? And shouldn't `malloc(10);` be `malloc(10*sizeof(int));`?

Comment: @CoolGuy -  regarding ***"*"sizeof(int)***,Yes on all counts.  But regarding where to call free, it can be called anywhere, depending on when it is no longer needed, and the scope of where it was created.  For this illustration, I think you make a good point because in the context of this example, it is a better illustration.   Thank you!  Edited

Answer (score 1):

Don't do malloc twice, it will lead to memory leak.

Just return fp after doing atof, you don't need result pointer.

You would store fp in your hashmap and free it when you are free-ing the hashmap.

Comment: _Don't do malloc twice, it will lead to memory leak_.  This _comment_ by itself is misleading.  Explain why you believe calling malloc twice will lead to memory leak.

Comment: Because the code is doing malloc for 2 pointers (unnecessary) and only the returned one will be retained for freeing later.

Comment: :) - I meant to suggest that you could edit your answer with that reason.

Answer (score 1):

1.You may not need to `malloc()` at all. Just use:

```
static float f;
if (strcmp(type, "float")==0) {
    f = atof(token_value);
    return (void *)&f;
}
```

2. Note that since your function `returns (void *)`, the caller will get the value but would not know the size.
3. Your code has a memory leak; you allocate space for 'result', then that space is lost when you assign 'result' the memory space allocated to 'fp' (by doing `'result = fp'`
4. if you really want to keep your code as is then:
   a. Remove the line `'void *result = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));`
   b. Indicate that the caller of the function must free it, i.e.

   ptr = (float *)parser_get_pointer(...)
       printf("value = %f\n", ptr);
       free(ptr);

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let's address some specific problems:

First, the following code is unnecessary *and* it introduces a memory leak:

```
void *result = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));
result = fp;
```

You assign the result of the `malloc` call to `result`, and then you immediately overwrite that value with `fp`.  Thus you lose the pointer value returned from `malloc`, meaning you won't be able to `free` that memory later.  You don't need to set aside additional memory to store the pointer value.

The way this code is written, you don't need the `result` variable at all; just return `fp`.

Second, don't cast the result of `malloc`<sup>1</sup> - as of the C89 standard it's unnecessary, and under C89 compilers it can suppress a useful diagnostic.  The cleanest way to write a `malloc` call is something like

```
 T *p = malloc( N * sizeof *p ); // for any type T
```

or

```
 T *p;
 ...
 p = malloc( N * sizeof *p );
```

The type of the expression `*p` is `T`, so `sizeof *p` gives the same result as `sizeof (T)`.  The `sizeof` operator doesn't attempt to evaluate the argument; it won't try to dereference `p`.

Neither do you need to cast the return value; in C, values of any pointer type can be converted to `void *` and back again without an explicit cast.

As for where to put the `free` call, that would be wherever you decide you don't need to store the pointed-to value anymore (such as removing that item from the hashmap).  That would be somewhere outside of the code you've posted.

---

<sup>1. C++ *does* require a cast, since C++ doesn't allow implicit conversions between `void *` and other pointer types, but if you were using C++ you wouldn't be messing around with naked pointers anyway.</sup>